# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs.loaderRef.hide')

Tags: react-native, ref

here is my store class
  .........
    import Loade from './utils/Loader';
    export default class store extends Component {

```
.................
render() {

        return (
           <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
             <Loader ref={"loaderRef"}/>
    ...........................
```

when I call       `this.refs.loaderRef.hide();`  from my store class

got an error like this
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs.loaderRef.hide')

I'm a newbie in react native,can anybody help me?

Comment: when you are getting this error ? on click on some function ?

Comment: in response of a post request  ..... .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (responseJson) => {   this.refs.loaderRef.hide(); }

Comment: could you please add some more code ?

Comment: `await fetch('' + aws_data.path + aws_data.stage + aws_lamda.contentmanagement, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':acceestoken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(reqobj),
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (responseJson) => {
        ......
        })
        this.refs.loaderRef.hide();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
       this.refs.loaderRef.hide();

        console.error(error);
      });`

Answer (score 2):

Its scope issue.

declare `this` with `_this`.

ex

```
let _this = this; //before api call
```

then use

```
_this.refs.loaderRef.hide
```

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that `loaderRef` is null, check you are initialising `loaderRef` properly.

Also check that, `this` will return you current component context when you call in lifecycle method, like in render() / componentWillMount(). But if you call `this` from your method it will return current method instance.

If this is problem then you can create a variable globally named `_this` and initialise inside `render()` or `constructor` like `_this = this;`. Then use it like `_this.refs.loaderRef.hide();`

For example

```
var _this;
export default class ScreenMyProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     _this = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i declare _this? in the start of the class?( sorry for asking silly quests,I'm totally new to this)

Comment: declare before calling await fetch

Comment: @ben10 See example in answer